# Render item based on roles assigned to another controller/action

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core 2 on Windows, on a view in say controller 1, I have a number of links that point to actions of controller 2. Those actions are annotated with Authorize attribute. For example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\Group1, Domain\Group1")]
[Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\User1")]
public IActionResult DisplaySomething()
{
    return View();
}
```

I don't want to create/render the links if the current user does not have access to that controller/action. So from view of controller 1, how do I check if the user is authorized to call actions of controller 2?

Answer (score 1):

In the most primitive way you put the following in your view.

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Domain\Group1"))
{
    <div>Only visible for Domain\Group1 users</div>
}
```

It is better to make an `HtmlHelper` out of this.

To prevent that the rolenames get distributed throughout your application you can work with [policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt826337.aspx).

Instead of roles you, you specify a policy name on the action method to configure access to this method.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
public IActionResult DisplaySomething()
{
    return View();
}
```

In the view you decide whether to render something via a check by this policy name.

```
@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "MyPolicy")).Succeeded)
{
    <div>Only visible for users matching the rules defined in policy MyPolicy</div>
}
```

In `ConfigureServices` you specify eg. which roles should be checked in the given policy.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization(options => {

        options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy => {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireRole("Domain\Group1");
        // ...
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Good to know about policies! However, first, I am trying to avoid having role or policy names hard coded into views because they can get out of sync when they change in the controller/action decorations. Second, the roles could be in an AND or OR configuration on the controller which the view logic should not know about. I guess I am looking for a function that I can call from a view that looks like this: bool IsAuthorized(User user, string controller, string action)    Maybe there is a way to do this through Reflection?

Comment: I totally agree, have a look at HtmlHelpers or TagHelpers; you can write one that can ben used in your view as eg. `@html.IsUserAnAdmin()`; the names of the groups (or policies) being AND/OR'ed go into that function. You can write these as you please, they are just functions.